# Google PubSub and duplicated messages from the TOPIC

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

How to prevent duplicated msg from happening in Google Cloud PubSub?

Say, I have a code that handles the msg that it is subscribed for.

Say, I have 2 nodes with the same Service that has this code.

Once one has received the msg but not yet acknowledged it, another node will receive the same message. And this is where there's the problem that we have two **duplicated msgs**.

```
void messageReceiver(PubsubMessage pubsubMessage, AckReplyConsumer ackReply) {

        submitHandler.handle(toMessage(pubsubMessage))
                .doOnSuccess((response) -> {
                    log.info("Acknowledging the successfully processed message id: {}, response {}", pubsubMessage.getMessageId(), response);
                    ackReply.ack();  // <---- acknowledged
                })
                .doOnError((e) -> {
                    log.error("Not acknowledging due to an exception", e);
                    ackReply.nack();
                })
                .doOnTerminate(span::finish)
                .subscribe();
    }
```

What is the solution for this? Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: What is the `Acknowledgement Deadline`?

Comment: did not setup it specifically should be 10 seconds by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub uses "At-Least-Once" delivery. From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery):

> Typically, Cloud Pub/Sub delivers each message once and in the order in which it was published. However, messages may sometimes be delivered out of order or more than once. In general, accommodating more-than-once delivery requires your subscriber to be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning) when processing messages.

This means it guarantees it will deliver the message 1:N times, so you can potentially get the message multiple times if you don't pipe it through something else that deduplicates it first. There isn't a setting you can define to guarantee exactly once delivery. The docs do reference you can get the behavior you desire using Cloud Dataflow's `PubSubIO`, but [that solution appears to be deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io):

> You can achieve exactly once processing of Cloud Pub/Sub message streams using Cloud Dataflow [`PubsubIO`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io). PubsubIO de-duplicates messages on custom message identifiers or those assigned by Cloud Pub/Sub.

Saying all of this, I've never *actually* seen Google Cloud Pub/Sub send a message twice. Are you sure that's really the problem you're having, or is the message being reissued because you are not acknowledging the message within the Acknowledgement Deadline (as you stated above, this defaults to 10 seconds). If you don't acknowledge it, it will get reissued. From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#create) **(emphasis mine)**:

> A subscription is created for a single topic. It has several properties that can be set at creation time or updated later, including:
>
> - An [acknowledgment deadline](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#ack_deadline): **If your code doesn't acknowledge the message before the deadline, the message is sent again.** The default is 10 seconds. The maximum custom deadline you can specify is 600 seconds (10 minutes).

If that's the situation, just acknowledge your messages within the deadline and you won't see these duplicates as often.

Comment: we do acknowledge them. and we did not see duplicates in non-prod when testing them. only on prod:)

Comment: if it is 1:N times, then, I guess, we may use something like in-memory data-grid solution to keep records of what already acknowledged  to skip duplicates if they happened on each service instance. if this sounds like nice solution.. sure it overcomplicates things.

Comment: Maybe you can add some tracing to guarantee these requests are less than 10 seconds? We're using the same service, and I don't run into the issues you're describing. We also specify a 5-minute acknowledgement deadline though...

Comment: @ses - You have to be prepared for duplicate messages (read the docs). However, I have never seen a duplicate message. My timeout is also 300 seconds.

Comment: I am afraid to use Pubsub because of duplicating messages, in our application it mean that user can receive a message (message inside our application) twice :(

Comment: 2021 now. Have you seen any duplicate? It annoys me that they don't have a system that just won't send again AT ALL if I have ack'ed it. Can't GOOGLE do it?

Comment: @HenriqueBruno I can confirm that message duplication does happen.
We've identified ~160 occasions during the last 3 months in our Big Data environment where we use PubSub based Cloud Functions to trigger Airflow DAGs via REST API (in Cloud Composer) on combination of time and file based events (arrival of .okay files onto the storage and Cloud Scheduler with config "*/5 * * * *"). The average trigger count was around 2000/day.

Comment: @HenriqueBruno fwiw, since they can't deliver every feature on day one, they have to prioritize, and the best practices for message bus consumption is to make your operation idempotent which nullifies the concern of dupes which was a good starting point for the short and mid term. Beyond that, they have another solution using data flow to dedupe (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/pubsub-spring-dedup-messages). I was talking to one of their product managers for pub sub a couple weeks ago, and iirc, she mentioned that native dupe detection was on the roadmap.

Comment: Also, if you're using PubSub as an event source, then... heh... I don't envy you. I'd suggest using a stream instead. That'll give you at-most-once delivery (subjective, it's a consumer concern to only read the index once) as well as message ordering. PubSub can give you the latter, but *kinda* give you the former right now with some extra work.

Comment: In case anyone's interested, we are seeing messages duplicated at a rate of about 0.00008 (e.g. 104063246 messages in total, 7992 of which were duplicated)

Answer (score 6):

You can use Redis from Memorystore in order to deduplicate messages. Your publisher should add trace iD to the message body just before publishing it to PubSub. On the other side client (subscriber) should check if the trace ID is in the cache - skip the message. If there is no such message - process the message and add trace ID to cache with 7-8 days expiry time (PubSub deadline is 7 days). In such a simple way You can grant the correct messages received.

Answer (score 1):

All messages in a given topic have a unique [`messageID`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) field:

> ID of this message, assigned by the server when the message is published. **Guaranteed to be unique within** the topic. This value may be read by a subscriber that receives a PubsubMessage via a subscriptions.pull call or a push delivery. It must not be populated by the publisher in a topics.publish call.

You can use it to deduplicate incoming messages. No need to manually assigning ID.

It is a bit harder in distributed systems (e.g. multiple instances of consumers for a given subscription). You would need a global synchronization mechanism, the simplest would be to setup database (e.g. Redis) and use it to keep processed messages IDs.

You should take a look at [Replaying and discarding messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview) which describes how to configure message retention.

There are two properties of subscription:

- `retain_acked_messages` - keep acknowledge messages,
- `message_retention_duration` - how long to keep messages.

If you do not plan to rewind your subscription to a past point in time, e.g. if you do not plan to reprocess messages or have bugs forcing you to reset your subscription you can set **`retain_acked_messages=false`** and **`message_retention_duration='3600s'`**. This will allow you to keep only last hour message IDs.

Bear in mind that PubSub message also have [`publish_time`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) so you don't need to add it in your message's data. It can be used with `message_id`. Both of these are set by a PubSub server when it receives a message.